# Remover caracteres que estiverem antes de outro

Tags: java, replace

Meu professor pediu para fazer um método que cancela um caractere numa frase usando o `#` que cancela o caractere anterior, exemplo:

Entrada: `PUO#C MIP#NO#AS`

Saída: `PUC MINAS`

Porém, meu código dá erro quando uso o método `replace` ou `replaceAll` para retirar e trocar por um caractere vazio. Segue o meu código abaixo:

```java
public void Elimina(String frase) {

        for (int j = 0; j<frase.length(); j++) {
            if (frase.charAt(j) == '#') {
                frase = frase.replace(frase.charAt(j), '');
                frase = frase.replace(frase.charAt(j-1), '-');
            }
        }

        System.out.println(frase);      
    }
```

OBS:

`frase = frase.replace(frase.charAt(j), '');` -> O erro dá nessa linha no `''`.

`frase = frase.replace(frase.charAt(j-1), '-');` -> Aqui é para mostrar que ao substituir o método funciona.

Comment: Compartilhe o código como texto (e formatado aqui no SO) ao invés de em imagem. E deixe mais claro também qual erro acontece. Isso faz com que sua pergunta seja mais útil para quem pesquisar no futuro.

Comment: Não só para que outras pessoas possam pesquisar no futuro, mas é porque é mais fácil você postar o seu código como código para que quem vá responder possa copiar e colar esse código do que querer que quem vá responder tenha que redigitar tudo de novo.

Comment: `charAt` retorna um `char` mas `replaceAll` deve receber `String`'s, então o código nem compila. Dito isso, por que  o caractere na posição `j - 1`  está sendo substituído por `-`? Não é para eliminar ele também?

Comment: @hkotsubo https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char) - O que não compila é o `''`.

Comment: Ah, confundi com `replaceAll`... Falha nossa

Comment: Uma série de ótimos motivos para não postar fotos de códigos, erros e logs e ao invés disso usar texto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635 -- respeitar as dicas e regras é respeitar o site e a comunidade, aceite as dicas, elas são para o bem de todos. Seja bem vindo.

Comment: @RafaelTavares código reeditado e o erro acontece no substituir por vazio, como mostrado na observação.

Comment: @hkotsubo, quando coloquei o '-' é para mostrar que funciona, mas quando coloco '' não funciona, apenas para evidenciar o erro.

Comment: Isso não tinha ficado claro. De qualquer forma, era muito mais fácil colocar a mensagem de erro que apareceu aí (sempre que dá erro, ainda mais de compilação, aparece alguma mensagem em algum lugar) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo
Não coloquei a mensagem de erro pois antes de o compilar já fica sublinhado de vermelho, como dito no '', onde é apontado o erro.

Comment: Isso é erro de compilação então o erro não ocorre antes de compilar, e sim durante :-) E sempre aparece uma mensagem de erro em algum lugar (em muitos editores ou tem um console/janela separada que mostra os erros ou vc coloca o cursor/mouse sobre o ponto que dá erro e a mensagem aparece)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro você usar um `StringBuilder`. Você vai copiando nele os caracteres um a um, mas quando achar um `#`, você deleta o último.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(elimina("PUO#C MIP#NO#AS"));
    }

    public static String elimina(String frase) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(frase.length());
        for (int j = 0; j < frase.length(); j++) {
            if (frase.charAt(j) == '#') {
                sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
            } else {
                sb.append(frase.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/yg0hVH).

Comment: Victor Stafusa
Muito obrigado pela ajuda, não conhecia as funcionalidades do StringBuilder, ajudou muito.
Valeu!!!

Comment: @VictorHenrique Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.

Answer (score 4):

Como é um exercício, *provavelmente* o professor quer que use um *loop*, e aí você pode usar o código da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445730/112052).

Mas só para deixar registrado uma alternativa:

```
public String elimina(String frase) {
    return frase.replaceAll(".#", "");    
}
```

Eu usei a regex `.#`. O ponto corresponde a [qualquer caractere](https://regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (exceto quebras de linha), então ela pega qualquer caractere seguido de `#` e substitui pela string vazia (o que na prática é o mesmo que remover estes caracteres).

Também mudei o método para retornar a string em vez de imprimí-la. Assim quem chamar o método obtém o resultado e pode fazer o que quiser com ele (inclusive imprimir, claro, mas essa responsabilidade não deveria ficar na função).

E coloquei o nome começando com letra minúscula para ficar aderente com as convenções de código do Java.

Exemplo de uso:

```
System.out.println(elimina("PUO#C MIP#NO#AS"));
```

O código acima imprime "PUC MINAS".

---

A regex também já trata de um *corner case*, que é quando a string começa com `#`. Nesse caso, entendo que o `#` não deveria ser removido, já que não há um caractere anterior (e a regex acima já faz isso, pois a substituição só ocorre se tiver um caractere antes do `#`).

Mas se quiser remover o caractere `#` também se ele estiver no início da string, basta mudar a regex para `".?#"`. O `?` indica que o caractere antes do `#` é [opcional](https://regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Comment: Ótima explicação e não sabia desse método, muito bom para conhecimento. Muito obrigado.